# CSV quotes + comma separators and BREAK LINE : import in EXCELwithout break line

Tags: excel, csv, line-breaks, csv-import

I have this kind of CSV :

[image: EXCEL CSV BREAK LINE]

So when I import in **EXCEL 2013** with "get data from text file",

**1)  how to say separator IS QUOTES + COMMA**,

**2) For Excel,  BREAK LINE in fields are new line of data... how to say it's not ?**

I know that CSV are a long topic on the Web, but there is no obvious solution.
So thanks for your help.

Comment: This is called a 'text qualifier'. When you are importing, what do you set the text qualifier to?

Comment: I set COMMA for field separator et QUOTES for text qualifier.

Comment: In spite of that, Excel create a new data line in import, when there is a new line INSIDE a field (in quotes)

Comment: Try avoid the Text Import Wizard. If it is a `*.csv` file, just open it in Excel using `File - Open`.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: I would first fix the file:**

```
Sub ImportData()
    Dim dataTextFile As String
    Dim outTextFile As String, splitPart As String, missingPart As String, ret As String
    '---Read the file---
    Open "C:\Data.txt" For Input As #1
    dataTextFile = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1

    dataTextFile = Replace(dataTextFile, vbNewLine, "[NEW_LINE]")

    ret = GetRegex("(.*?,.*?,.*?),")
    outTextFile = outTextFile & ret & vbNewLine

    Do While 1
        If (ret = GetRegex(dataTextFile, ",(.*?,.*?,.*?)")) <> "" Then
           Exit Do
        Else
            outTextFile = outTextFile & ret & vbNewLine
            dataTextFile = Right(dataTextFile, Len(dataTextFile) - Len(ret))
        End If
    Loop
    '---Write back to the file---
    Open "C:\Data.txt" For Output As #1
    Write #1, outTextFile
    Close #1
End Sub
```

You can find the GetRegex function here: [link](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-split-columns-pattern/). Or just use the general Regex object. Warning: I haven't tested the code so you might need to do some tinkering.

**Step 2: Next you simply import the file normally via the Import Wizar**d as comma separated file.

**Step 3: Lastly replace "[NEW_LINE]" with New Line characters** via macro or whatever other way.

Alternatively you may just as well do steps 2-3 in the same macro - and use the Right function or a Regex to extract the column to your output worksheet.